# how to consume post data when content type isapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded .net core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, model-binding

I have a use case where i need to accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post data and also consume querystring

```
[httpPost]
public void GetDetails([FromQuery] username)
{
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
   {
       try
       {
           var line = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
       }
       catch(exception ex)
       {
         //Do something
       } 
   }
}
```

For that when i try above `Request.Body` stream is `null`,

I have a solution to remove `[FromQuery]` and read querystring via `Reqeust.QueryString` but do we have any other options

Answer (score 1):

`[FromQuery]` and `[FromForm]` can be used in conjunction with each other to bind parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetDetails([FromQuery] string username, [FromForm] string formData) {
    //...Do something
    return Ok();
}
```

While the above example is taking the form data in a string, it can also be used to bind to more complex objects if needed.

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)